# Href to another file section does not reach this section (Bootstrap template)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got problem with navigating to file sections from another files. I am using Bootstrap one page template, that I am changing to multipage website. Within the same file navigation to sections works perfectly but when I try to access sections from another files new file is displaying in place somwhere above the called section.

I am using standard call:

```
<a href="newfile.html#somesection">
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This may be due to the height of the page. if your section is not up to the window height then it will display your section in the middle. Edit CSS in your page

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Could you explain what do you mean writing: "section is not up to the window height"?

Comment: Your section does not have 100% height . There for the section might be appearing in the middle. Try adjusting the height of the page

Comment: But the page height depends on content. When I access the section from another page it displays much above the called section. The section is not in the middle just much lower then the place displayed after the call.

Comment: Is there any solution for my problem? Can anyone help?